# Flight controler isLowerThanBatteryWarningThreshold updates several seconds after the drone is returning home

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm writing a mobile SDK based app and I want to notify the users that there is an "isLowerThanBatteryWarningThreshold" warning and give them the chance to "cancelGoHome" through the app.
The problem is that until the warning state in the flight controller state callback is updated, the remote controller is already beeping for several seconds and the drone (Matrice 100) already starts landing.
is there a way to get/listen/catch the warning faster?

The android SDK version I am using is 4.4.1

Answer (score 1):

pls try to update to the latest version of MSDK, 4.7.1 has been released right now, or try to use the key: `IS_LOWER_THAN_BATTERY_WARNING_THRESHOLD` under `FlightControllerKey` class, it could directly notify the event, the following is a guide page in github about how to use the key:
https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/issues/248#issuecomment-371733561